# HTTPRequest.request with sendData, can't seem to get this to work

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm trying to wrap my head around Dart, and in doing so got stumped with adding some data to an HTTPRequest.  I need to send a parameter with this request, so I figured the "sendData" variable would probably help me do that.  Documentation is sparse at best for this method, so for all I know it's just my syntax that's wrong.  Any idea why this wouldn't work?

```dart
HttpRequest.request(url, sendData:{"rnd":rnd.millisecondsSinceEpoch}).then(onLoadSuccess).catchError(onLoadError);
```

Currently it tanks out in html_dartium.dart at

```dart
void send([data]) native "XMLHttpRequest_send_Callback";
```

And only tells me "String expected."  It doesn't say where the string is expected, so I'm stumped.  Any ideas/thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Can't test right now, but you might want to JSON.encode the sendData.

'If specified, `sendData` will send data in the form of a [ByteBuffer], [Blob], [Document], [String], or [FormData] along 
 with the HttpRequest. '

Comment: I'd love to try this, however, being a complete noob, I have no idea how to even import the JSON library.  Gonna keep hacking at it for now.

Comment: Just a quick update - I used json.stringify on the sendData, and now I get no error.  That said, I don't see the data I want to send in my request while running Charles.

Comment: The newest SDK requires you to import 'dart:convert' which holds a JSON object from which you can call JSON.encode(encodable). If you want to see which data is being sent you can open your browsers' developer tools and press the networking tab.