# HttpRequest GET with sendData as query parameters?

Tags: dart, dart-io

This question is kind of a duplicate of [HTTPRequest.request with sendData, can't seem to get this to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777665/httprequest-request-with-senddata-cant-seem-to-get-this-to-work), but I've got some more information now.  The goal here is to send a GET request with query parameters attached.  I initially tried to send my request as such:

```dart
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.open("GET", _url, async:true);
request.onError.listen(_onLoadError, onError: _onLoadError);
request.send(sendData);
```

Where sendData is a String following the normal format for query parameters (?myVariable=2&myOtherVariable=a, etc), since this is the ultimate goal here.  The request gets sent, but I never see any additional data (sendData) go with it in any monitoring tools (I'm using Charles).  I then tried:

```dart
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.open("GET", _url + sendData, async:true);
request.onError.listen(_onLoadError, onError: _onLoadError);
request.send();
```

So now I'm just attaching the query string to the url itself.  This works as intended, but is far from elegant.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [W3 XMLHttpRequest Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method):

> (In the send() method) The argument is ignored if request method is GET or HEAD.

So simple answer to this question is no. sendData cannot be appended to a GET request, this is by XMLHttpRequest specification and not a limitation of Dart.

That said, for requests like this it may be more readable and idiomatic to use [HttpRequest.getString](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#getString)

```dart
HttpRequest.getString(_url + sendData).then((HttpRequest req) {
    // ... Code here
}).catchError(_onLoadError);
```

Answer (score 9):

On a `GET` request you always add the query string to the URL? 
When you create the `Uri` you can pass in a map with the query parameters if you find this more elegant.

```dart
Map query = {'xx':'yy', 'zz' : 'ss'};
String url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signinService";

Uri uri = new Uri(path: url, queryParameters : query);

HttpRequest.getString(uri.toString().then((HttpRequest req) ...
```

Comment: The above code results following error
`Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI http%3A//xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/v2/api/devices/?ids=A0`

Comment: I assume because of `%3A`

Comment: `Uri(path: url, queryParameters : query)`  results '%3A' which is encoded form of `:` . Any workaround on this?

Comment: Because `http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` is not a path. Use `Uri.parse('....')` and then update the uri with the query parameters.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a valid URL from url (String) + query parameters (Map) , you can do the following :

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(url).replace(queryParameters: parameters);
 String finalURL = uri.toString();
```

url is a `String` and parameters is a `Map`